# How to call a function when reference is assigned in custom inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to call/trigger a function when a reference is assigned via a custom editor.

Outside the inspector I would take care of it like this:

```
[SerializeField]
private SomeMember _someMemberRef;
public SomeMember someMemberRef{ get { return _someMemberRef; } set { _someMemberRef= value; someFunction(); } }
```

But since the custom inspector directly assigns to the private _someMemberRef, someFunction() will not be called.

```
EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("_someMemberRef"));
```

Is there a way to call/trigger someFunction() when the assignment happens in the inspector?

Comment: does that really compile?

Comment: maybe there is a better way to achieve what you are trying to do. What exactly would you need it to update for on assignment?

Comment: I'd like to display some additional information in my custom inspector that is calculated based on members of _someRef. So when _someRef is replaced by another SomeClass object reference I need to recalculate this information because the values of _someRefs members might have changed.

Comment: I would just add a recalculate button, or you can just use the `OnInspectorGUI()` function as an update function like this link shows http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/333181/how-do-you-force-a-custom-inspector-to-redraw.html

Comment: If there is no other way, I might end up calling it every OnInspectorGUI() but I don't like the redundant calls. I'd prefer to only call someFunction() when necessary. The button idea might be useful for some people, but I would feel uncomfortable with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the class for which the custom inspector is intended is called SomeClass and has a member *private SomeMember _someMemberRef* with a *public SomeMember someMemberRef* getter and setter as mentioned above:

Instead of using

```
EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("_someMemberRef"));
```

in the corresponding Editor-derived class, one can use

```
SomeClass someClassRef = (SomeClass) target;
SomeMember someMemberRef = null;
someMemberRef = (SomeMember)EditorGUI.ObjectField(EditorGUILayout.GetControlRect(), "Some Member Ref", someClassRef.someMemberRef, typeof(SomeMember), false);
if (someMemberRef != someClassRef.someMemberRef)
{
    someClassRef.someMemberRef = someMemberRef;
    someClassRef.someFunction();
}
```

To call any public function upon assignment in the inspector. It also works with EditorGUILayout.ObjectField if someone isn't comfortable with working with rects.